# Json to Array using javascript xhttp

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, xhtml

So I'am getting a Json string from an API using js xhttp, bet I can't seem to get the json converted in an array to specify an value.

I have tried using JSON.parse() but it always returns [object object]. Whenever I dont use JSON.parse(), it will give the string version of the json.

This is the code for getting the json from the API:

```
function showHint(str) {
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //alert(obj)
      //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = obj;
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = obj ;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/locatieserver/v3/suggest?q=type:adres%20"+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

And for the html:

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" placeholder="test"/>
</form>
<span id="txtHint"></span>
```

Here is an example URL for the API: https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/locatieserver/v3/suggest?q=type:adres%20haviklaan

I want to isolate all the "weergavenaam" values.
for axample if the JSON gives "weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 1A, Katwijk" I want the "Haviklaan 1A, Katwijk" part as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to enter full path to the first object, like so:

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = obj.response.docs[0].weergavenaam;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig into the object a little deeper and `map()` over the `docs` array to get an array of the `weergavenaam` values you want. `map()` will give you an array of the values, if you want a single string you can use something like `join()`:

```js
let obj = {"response":{"numFound":258,"start":0,"maxScore":12.414675,"docs":[{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 1A, Katwijk","id":"adr-d10af16641607326ce22354641c07c5c","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 1T, Katwijk","id":"adr-e5dfad15bdd9db8aac42138d3c4dee3c","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 11A, Katwijk","id":"adr-e886a238089b5ea455a204189576814c","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 13A, Katwijk","id":"adr-9b001e099efc6555542269e64fc0c61a","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 23A, Katwijk","id":"adr-d9c85d4b6cb3a635921219e0e35b1852","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 25A, Katwijk","id":"adr-30f73ed847865b7ee7d5da1c8aeb4cbc","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 35A, Katwijk","id":"adr-2de61dda0a2bd7876580570af388d10c","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 37A, Katwijk","id":"adr-df3596c0fb92d665cef1ca68ed664c7f","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 47A, Katwijk","id":"adr-03e73c776f0d8169b97e15607afc09cb","score":12.414675},{"type":"adres","weergavenaam":"Haviklaan 49A, Katwijk","id":"adr-7a08cb658d9b037aee69ec1ca7cb4b7f","score":12.414675}]},"highlighting":{"adr-d10af16641607326ce22354641c07c5c":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 1A, Katwijk"]},"adr-e5dfad15bdd9db8aac42138d3c4dee3c":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 1T, Katwijk"]},"adr-e886a238089b5ea455a204189576814c":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 11A, Katwijk"]},"adr-9b001e099efc6555542269e64fc0c61a":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 13A, Katwijk"]},"adr-d9c85d4b6cb3a635921219e0e35b1852":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 23A, Katwijk"]},"adr-30f73ed847865b7ee7d5da1c8aeb4cbc":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 25A, Katwijk"]},"adr-2de61dda0a2bd7876580570af388d10c":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 35A, Katwijk"]},"adr-df3596c0fb92d665cef1ca68ed664c7f":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 37A, Katwijk"]},"adr-03e73c776f0d8169b97e15607afc09cb":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 47A, Katwijk"]},"adr-7a08cb658d9b037aee69ec1ca7cb4b7f":{"suggest":["<b>Haviklaan</b> 49A, Katwijk"]}},"spellcheck":{"suggestions":[],"collations":[]}}

let weergavenaam = obj.response.docs.map(obj => obj.weergavenaam)
console.log(weergavenaam.join(', '))
```